# How to add click function to a array of buttons which is added dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, node.js

Here's the code:

```js
for(var i=0;i<quick_r.length;i++) {
                    
                    quick_messages[i] = '<button type="button" class="quick" id="quick' + quick_count + '">'+quick_r[i]["title"]+ '</button>';
                    quick_count++;
                    replyID[i] = '#quick'+quick_count; 
                    console.log(replyID[i]);
                }
```

I want to add a click function to that button in the loop which is generated dynamically depending upon number of quick_r
I added Ids to the buttons dynamically with the help of that loop

Comment: Using event delegaton...

Comment: Can you explain in detail @MilindAnantwar

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: For dynamically added HTML @Abhi

Comment: @leo It shouldn't matter, if the function you are calling as part of `onclick` is already defined. You may pass the object reference to the function to detect each element individually. Eg: `onclick="func_1(this);"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery 1.7+ you can attach an event handler to a parent element using .on(), and pass the a selector combined with class as an argument.

```
$('parentTag').on('click', 'quick', function() {
    //do some work.
});
```

Add your dynamically created button inside the parent tag or you can pass 'body' tag as well.